# Rails which files to ignore for GIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I created a GIT repo, locally. I now see a bunch of files i rather ignore for GIT check-in.  This brings me to the question: is there any default .gitignore for Rails?  Any best practices?

I think of *tmp* and *log* for sure. But are there any other files or folders i should consider?

Comment: Rails should have generated a `.gitignore` file for you with the most common non-source-control files included already

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Github has sample `.gitignore` files for almost any kind of project known to humanity in [their github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) repository.

There is one specifically for Rails:
[Rails.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Rails.gitignore)

Comment: This answer is incredibly awesome.

Comment: I need a "favorite answer" star system.

Comment: The Rails file under this Repo is at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Rails.gitignore

Answer (score 13):

this is a gitignore from a relatively large Rails 3.2 app (created with Rails 3.1)

```
/.bundle
/db/*.sqlite3
/log/*.log
/tmp
config/database.yml
config/google_analytics.yml
.DS_Store
/nbproject/
public/assets/**
```

just the basic gitignore which comes with rails and added some developer specific stuff like Netbeans project stuff, the .DS_Store from OS X

and we don't like passwords in our repository, so we add all yml files with passwords to gitignore

we also added public/assets/** since we deploy our apps with capistrano and generate the assets during the deploy and push them to amazon

Comment: thx. i need to look into that, since it was not working. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

.git/info/exclude
If you wish the exclude patterns based on repositories , you may instead put them in a file in that specific repository named .git/info/exclude or core.excludesfile

.gitignore is used to add files which you don't want to be tracked.
If the file is already being tracked and you want to add to .gitignore.
run git rm --cached filename

Answer (score 2):

Make use of this [GITIGNORE.IO](https://www.gitignore.io)

```
### Rails ###
*.rbc
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/log
/tmp
/config/database.yml
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/public/system
/coverage/
/spec/tmp
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html

# TODO Comment out these rules if you are OK with secrets being uploaded to the repo
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/secrets.yml

## Environment normalisation:
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle

# these should all be checked in to normalise the environment:
# Gemfile.lock, .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset

# unless supporting rvm < 1.11.0 or doing something fancy, ignore this:
.rvmrc

# if using bower-rails ignore default bower_components path bower.json files
/vendor/assets/bower_components
*.bowerrc
bower.json

#Ignore pow enironment settings
.powenv
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails already generate a .gitignore file for you with good defaults. You think right, in fact the .gitignore generated by rails already ignores tmp and log file (and the DBs too).

Comment: must be hidden @Rogier

Comment: @zack, nah it was not there (i know hidden are staring with . [dot]).

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the direct link](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Rails.gitignore) to the Rails gitignore file. It is up I found this by a simple google search.

You can modify it as per your project/tools settings. I had to add `.idea/` to it which is automatically generated by Rubymine.