# Why is Rails assets pipeline generate different .gz files generated every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I added the assets to git and then ran `rake assets:precompile` again. But now the gz files are all changed. But the plain text css and js files are not.

Why have the gz files changed?

[image]

Comment: gzipped files contain the last-modified timestamp so the `.gz` can change even if the file's content doesn't change.

Comment: the gods of semantic search hate you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not add the gzip files to you source control system.
I will change, because every time you create a new gzip file, even if the contents are the same, the resulting file will be different, and source control systems don't know how to deal with this (and it's not supposed to do it).

You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9616362/1006863) to know what files to add to gitignore.

Also you can take a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2817) about it in github.